# How to compare array and render elements in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, equals, styled-components

I have two arrays of numbers, in the first array (CARD_ARRAY) there are X numbers (1 from 30, for example) and array 2 have X random numbers, in this case, let's use 10 random numbers
.

When the number is equal, the background-color is black, when not, is white.
I've been use styled-components `<Number choose />` is when numbers match and `<Number choose />` is for don't.

My problem is how to create a component and render, i did create a component that compare the two arrays an check if the numbers is equals:

```
const NumbersRow = (num: any) => {    
   CARD_ARRAY.map((CARD_NUM: number) => {
          numeros.map((num: number) => {
            if (CARD_NUM === num) {
              return (
                <Number choose>{CARD_NUM}</Number>
              )
            } else {
              return (
                <Number>{CARD_NUM}</Number>
              )
            }
          })
        })
}
```

In page : `{NumbersRow numbers={item.numbers} />`

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks btw.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What is the problem you are facing. Is the component not rendering on page ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can do something like this.
In the CARD_ARRAY map, Check the `CARD_NUM` exist in `numeros` using the `includes` method. Based on this, you can pass the prop (color choice) to component

```
CARD_ARRAY.map((CARD_NUM: number) => (
  <Number choose={numeros.includes(CARD_NUM) ? "black" : "white"}>
    {CARD_NUM}
  </Number>
));
```